# SVG in content or background?

Tags: html, css, svg

i have svg:

```
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='24' height='24' viewBox='002424' fill='none'>
    <path d='M1216C14.2091161614.20911612C169.7908614.20918128C9.79086889.79086812C814.20919.79086161216Z' stroke='#403f3d' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'/>
    <path d='M316V8C35.238585.23858383H16C18.76143215.23858218V16C2118.761418.7614211621H8C5.2385821318.7614316Z' stroke='#403f3d'/>
    <path d='M17.56.51L17.516.49889' stroke='#403f3d' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'/>
</svg>
```

is it possible to use it in a `::after` pseudo selector?
should I use content or background?

I tried to do this, but it didn't work

```
.selector::after {
  position: relative;
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml; base64, <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='24' height='24' viewBox='002424' fill='none'><path d='M1216C14.2091161614.20911612C169.7908614.20918128C9.79086889.79086812C814.20919.79086161216Z' stroke='#403f3d' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'/><path d='M316V8C35.238585.23858383H16C18.76143215.23858218V16C2118.761418.7614211621H8C5.2385821318.7614316Z' stroke='#403f3d'/><path d='M17.56.51L17.516.49889' stroke='#403f3d' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'/></svg>");
}
```

Comment: It should be either a CSS `background-image` or be in the HTML. But it totally depends if it is a part of the content, like a descriptive icon, or just decoration, like a background shape.

Comment: Problems with the SVG: 1 not a valid viewBox value 2. not a valid d attribute for the paths. I suspect you may have a program that ignore spaces